# Extract from SOAP response XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

I receive a response from an API, and at the moment I am doing this with it

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($serverResponse);
print_r($xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('urn:xtk:queryDef')->asXML());
```

That gets me down to the following

```
<ExecuteQueryResponse xmlns="urn:xtk:queryDef" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><pdomOutput xsi:type="ns:Element" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml">
    <recipient account="7777777777"/></pdomOutput>
</ExecuteQueryResponse>
```

What I am trying to do is extract the value for account.  How would I go about getting this value?

Thanks

Comment: Try using XPath. See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/.

Comment: Are you using the built-in SoapClient with a WSDL?  How did you get the response?  Parsing XML should not be necessary in this case.